# The subject in "How much information is created daily?"

Tags: syntax, subjects

> How much information is created daily?

If the subject is only implied in this sentence, why do we need the auxiliary verb (*is*) in this sentence?

Comment: What do you think the subject of this would be? What leads you to think that the subject is only implied?

Comment: I thought that "people" could be the subject. I didn't think that "information" was the subject because it would be incorrect to place "is" before it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is written in a passive voice. Notice the distinction in active voice and passive voice by the information below.

- "I create information." (active voice)
- "Information is created." (passive voice)

In the first sentence (active voice), the subject is "I" and the direct object is "information." However, in the second sentence, "information" becomes the subject. It's just another way to write the same idea without needing to specify who or what created the information. In doing so, we usually regard what was originally the direct object (information) now as the subject.

Thus, in your original sentence, "information" is the subject, but who or what is creating the information is intentionally not specified. The word "information" is the subject of the verb "to be"/"is".

Comment: Slight quibble: I would say that _how much information_ is the subject.

Comment: If "information" is the subject, why can't I say "How much is information created daily?". I mean, "is" (as well as other auxillary verbs) are usually placed before subject in interrogative sentences...

Comment: Things get funky in passive voice constructions like these. Look at these possible sentences. (1) There is one cat, (2) there are two cats. Here, the verb agrees with the subject, witch is placed after the verb. In question form, the construction is inverted so the subject is first: How many cats are there?